# NodeJS mysql2 Bluebird?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, bluebird, mysql2

Been testing mysql vs mysql2, seems like 2 has made some improvments however it's not an exact drop in replacement. At the same time Q is a good library which seems easier to integrate with however bluebird seems to take less memory and run faster so...

My current mysql-bluebird connector is as follows and allows for straight forward use of `query('SELECT email FROM users.users WHERE id=?',id).then(function(res){var email=res[0][0];});`

```
/* global module, require */
var conf=require('./conf.js').conf;
var mysql = require('mysql');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var using = Promise.using;
Promise.promisifyAll(require('mysql/lib/Connection').prototype);
Promise.promisifyAll(require('mysql/lib/Pool').prototype);

var pool = mysql.createPool(conf.mysql);

var getConnection = function () {
 return pool.getConnectionAsync().disposer(function (connection) {
 return connection.release();
 });
};
var query = function (command) {
 return using(getConnection(), function (connection) {
 return connection.queryAsync(command);
 });
};
function queryWrapper(q,a){
  if(a){
    return query(mysql.format(q,a));
  }
  else{
    return query(mysql.format(q));
  }
}
module.exports = {
 query: queryWrapper
};
```

So far my attempts ad doing this with mysql2 haven't panned out.

Does anyone have any insights on how to convert this?
Thanks, Jegsar

Comment: why you don't just use public api? You still make wrapper function for `query` anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mysql2-promise](https://github.com/namshi/node-mysql2-promise). It's a simple wrapper, using q, that promisifies mysql2. If you'd rather use Bluebird, you can look at how this wrapper was created and do it yourself.

Comment: I have looked at it and bit, but Q isn't a perfect drop in replacement for Bluebird especially on how they `promisify` callbacks. Reason for bluebird is performance/ram. Maybe it was how I implemented Q compared to Bluebird but since switching memory usage dropped TO 6% of what it was... with the amount of data that is saving 5gb+ of ram

Comment: hi Jegsar, I'll probably add promise support to mysql2 core ( with optionally pluggable Promise implementation ) - see  https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/pull/269  Feedback welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

node-mysql2 now has [Promise api built in](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2#promise-wrappers), and you can choose which promise implementation you want to use

```
var mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
mysql.createConnection({
  Promise: require('bluebird'), // if not set, global Promise is used
  user: 'foo',
  password: 'bar',
  database: 'baz'
})
 .then((conn) => conn.query('select 1+1 as test'))
 .then(([rows, fields]) => console.log(rows[0]))
```